# Distributing Enterprise Apps yourself for iOS 4 Devices not working on iOS 5

Tags: ios5

When I distribute Enterprise apps myself it works fine on devices with iOS 4.x but not on iOS 5.x devices. The info on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html doesn't help me unfortunately.

Anyone any advice what could be the reason it's not working ?

Thank you
Frank

UPDATE: fixed it, I had to remove the entry for iTunesArtwork in the plist because IIS7 couldn't find the artwork file

Comment: The error message is "Unable to download application" (but it works on iOS4)

Answer (score -1):

I think this error is because the iOS5 device you are using is not provisioned for  distribution. The error is not related to OS but provisioning. Check that you have added that device in provisioning portal of your apple developer account.

This link shows how to create distribution profile:

http://support.twixlmedia.com/kb/epublisher-builder-application/how-do-i-create-the-distribution-provisioning-profile-for-my-ad-hoc-build

Comment: provisioned for distribution ? It's an enterprise app, you don't have to add a device than. And btw the app runs perfectly when I run it from XCode on the iOS 5 device.